# Largest possible value of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Find the largest possible value of

$$\sin(a_1)\cos(a_2) + \sin(a_2)\cos(a_3) + \cdots + \sin(a_{2014})\cos(a_1)$$

Since the range of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ function is between $1$ and $-1$, shouldn't the answer be $2014$?

Comment: You cannot have $\sin (a_1)=\cos (a_1)=1$ so the maximum is not 2014.

Comment: Fairly obviously it won't exceed $2014$ but it does not necessarily achieve it either.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let $a_{2015}=a_1.$

Thus, by AM-GM
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\sin{a_k}\cos{a_{k+1}} \leq\sum_{k=1}^{2014}|\sin{a_k}||\cos{a_{k+1}}| \le$$
$$\leq\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{\sin^2a_k+\cos^2a_{k+1}}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{\sin^2a_k+\cos^2a_k}{2}=\frac{2014}{2}=1007.$$

The equality occurs for $a_i=45^{\circ},$ which says that $1007$ is a maximal value.

Comment: You mention AM-GM, which makes me expect to see a big sum turn into a big product at some point. But it never happens. Something clever is clearly going on in the third inequality -- but what? Could you expand this just a bit more?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner I used $ab\leq\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}.$

Comment: Ah! Very simple -- I kept trying to figure out where the calculation of a 2014th root went. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

From

$$
f_n(a) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sin a_k \cos a_{k+1}
$$

with $a_{n+1} = a_1$

the stationary points are located at the solutions for

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial a_k}f_n(a) = -\sin a_{k-1}\sin a_k + \cos a_k \cos a_{k+1} = 0
$$

and then

$$
\tan a_n\tan a_{n-1}\cdots\tan a_{2} = \cot a_1
$$

or

$$
\tan a_n\tan a_{n-1}\cdots\tan a_{2}\tan a_1 = 1
$$

or

$$
\prod_k\sin a_k = \prod_k\cos a_k
$$

which is obtained for $a_k = \frac{\pi}{4}$ when

$$
f_n(a) = \frac n2
$$

Comment: Nice answer. The calculus is easier than it looks at first. Is it obvious that $a_k=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is the absolute maximum? The $\tan a_n\tan a_{n-1}\cdots\tan a_{2}\tan a_1 = 1$ may have many solutions but I guess they are not all absolute maximum...

Comment: @Taladris There are many relative extrema. For instance for $n = 3$ we have: $\left\{-\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\right\}$ but with some additional considerations like symmetry...