# $f(n) = \sin(x_1)\cos(x_2) + \sin(x_2)\cos(x_3) +\cdots+ \sin(x_n)\cos(x_1)$, where $x_1 ,\ldots, x_n$ are any real numbers

Tags: trigonometry

> $$f(n) = \sin(x_1)\cos(x_2) + \sin(x_2)\cos(x_3) +\cdots+ \sin(x_n)\cos(x_1)$$
>
> $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad $where $x_1 ,\ldots, x_n$ are any real numbers.
>
> State which one(s) is/are correct:
>
> (A) $f(100) < 100$
>
> (B) $f(50) < 100$
>
> (C) $f(100) > 100$
>
> (D) $f(100) > 50$

My question is how do you solve or analyze these type of problems?

Comment: Did you have any thoughts about this?

Comment: Is $nx$ (the angle) in degrees or radians?

Comment: See the answer to this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875776/largest-possible-value-of-trigonometric-functions/2875794#2875794

Answer (score 1):

By using $ab\leq |a||b|\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ we derive that:

$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sin x_i\cos x_{i+1}+\sin x_n\cos x_1\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sin^2x_i+\cos^2x_{i+1}}{2}+\frac{\sin^2x_n+\cos^2x_1}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\sin^2x_i+\cos^2x_i}{2}=\frac{n}{2}$

Thus, (A,B) are correct, and (C,D) are not.

Answer (score 0):

Sine and cosine both have maximum values of $1$. Multiplying them does not change this. So $f(100)$ is the addition of less than 100 terms that cannot individually be greater than $1$. Did you notice this? Apply similar logic to choice B and notice that these are mutually exclusive to C and D respectively.